# pandas: adding missing values to dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

[image]

Hello! I have input data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 
                   'user':['User2', 'User3','User1','User1','User2','User2','User2','User3','User1','User1','User3'],
                   'c':[7,2,3,1,2,5,4,6,9,8,7]})
```

In the output data for the first week there is user1, and in the input data for the first week it is missing. I don't understand how I can automatically add it to the output. I would simply replace Nan, and in a situation of complete lack of data, the solution algorithm is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `user` column to categorical type, then group the dataframe and aggregate `c` with `sum`. The benefit of changing to categorical type is that the groupby will automatically account for missing users

```
df['user'] = df['user'].astype('category')
df1 = df.groupby(['w', 'user'], as_index=False).sum()
```

---

```
print(df1)

    w   user   c
0   1  User1   0
1   1  User2   7
2   1  User3   2
3   2  User1   4
4   2  User2   2
5   2  User3   0
6   3  User1   0
7   3  User2   9
8   3  User3   6
9   4  User1  17
10  4  User2   0
11  4  User3   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df_out = (
    dfs := df.groupby(["w", "user"])["cnt"]
    .sum()
    .reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
            [sorted(df["w"].unique()), sorted(df["user"].unique())], names=["w", "user"]
        ),
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .reset_index()
).assign(sum=dfs.groupby("user")["cnt"].transform("cumsum"))
```

Output:

```
    w   user  cnt  sum
0   1  User1    0    0
1   1  User2    7    7
2   1  User3    2    2
3   2  User1    4    4
4   2  User2    2    9
5   2  User3    0    2
6   3  User1    0    4
7   3  User2    9   18
8   3  User3    6    8
9   4  User1   17   21
10  4  User2    0   18
11  4  User3    7   15
```

Given input df as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':[1]*2+[2]*3+[3]*3+[4]*3,
                   'user':[f'User{i}' for i in [*'23112223113']], 
                   'cnt':[7,2,3,1,2,5,4,6,9,8,7]})
```